# Kafka connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available

Tags: apache-kafka

I am having 2 vms having kafka setup.In 2nd vm i have both ssl and plaintext kafka.

When am trying to access 1st vm topic list from 2nd vm, am getting desired result but while doing vice versa, am getting foll error:
Kafka connection to node -1 (/10.35.121.127:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

**server.properties of 1st vm:**

```
broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.75.166.240:39092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.75.166.240:39092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/root/kavit/data/kafka
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2189
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
security.protocol=SSL
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

**server.properties of 2nd vm:**

```
    broker.id=0
    advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://mybox-1.localdomain:9093,SSL://mybox-1.localdomain:9092
    listeners=PLAINTEXT://mybox-1.localdomain:9093,SSL://mybox-1.localdomain:9092
   listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL
    num.network.threads=3
    num.io.threads=8
    socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
    socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
    socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
    log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
    num.partitions=1
    num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
    offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
    transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
    transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
    log.retention.hours=168
    log.segment.bytes=1073741824
    log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
    zookeeper.connect=mybox-1.localdomain:2181
    zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
    group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
    ssl.keystore.location=/etc/security/Keys/keystore.jks
    ssl.keystore.password=abc
    ssl.key.password=abc
    ssl.truststore.location=/etc/security/Keys/truststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password=abc
```

I did run telnet and its givng No route to host.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Check whether connections is getting established from 2nd vm to 1st vm

Comment: @Jagadesh I tried ping ip address and the response was +ve.

Comment: Don't use ping. It doesn't check ports. Use telnet or `kcat -L`. Please show both server properties so we can try to reproduce.

Comment: @OneCricketeer telnet is giving no route to host error.

Comment: There you go, then. The IP or hostname you're using isn't resolvable... You need to put the machines on the same network

Comment: For starters, your `zookeeper.connect` isn't the same, so these aren't even part of the same cluster Also, according to the question, the first broker doesn't have an SSL listener

Comment: FWIW, I'd strongly suggest using something like Ansible for correctly creating a cluster , if you're opposed to using a cloud hosted solution and are required to use non containerized options.